# Symfony is_active field get 1,0 instead of true,false

Tags: php, symfony, boolean

In my symfony app I have a Page Entity and in this Entity I have a boolean variable. This is my code:

```
/**
 * @var Boolean $active whether page is active.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
 *
 * @JS\Groups({"pageDetail", "pageOwner"})
 */
protected $active;
```

I want to this variable in addition to true,false accept 0,1 and on,off.
Can I do it by event listeners?
How I do it?

Comment: Why? Wouldn't you be better to format the boolean as an integer or string (on/off) when you're using it for display/output but still store it as a boolean?

Comment: @RobbieAverill My program is an restfulbundle project and I would like users can send any amount they want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this requirements fully, but if you need to accept those values in the entity level, I will suggest that you absorb the difference in types in the setter method.

```
/**
 *
 * @param mixed $active
 */
public function setActive( $active ) {
    if ( $active )
       if ( is_string( $active ) ){
           if ( $active == '1' || $active == 'on' ){
               $this->active = true;
           }else if ($active == '0' || $active == 'off' ){
               $this->active = false;
           }   
       }else if ( is_bool( $active ) ){
           $this->active = $active;
       }
}
```

I also noticed that maybe you could consider altering the name of this member variable to $isActive instead of $active if column name is is_active.